# Dirac equation solution for a point particle

Tags: field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

I want to solve a Dirac equation with a special condition for the probabillity

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\psi=\delta\left(\vec{r}\right)$

Since Dirac spinor is a $4\times 1$ matrix, I am not sure what components should (or not) be set to zero and what should be set to some multiply of $\delta\left(\vec{r}\right)$

What is the solution of the Dirac equation with that special condition?

Comment: Dirac spinor is a spinor, which does have components as if it were a vector. Gamma matrices are matrices with spinor indices. If I guess correctly, you are trying to write the spinor components as a function of the delta's components, and I am not sure you can do that, especially with the delta being a tricky object

Comment: You get to choose between 4 components for this. Set electron spin down to zero and you can derive the version for electron spin up, etc. Another way to do this is to take free Dirac particle solutions and superpose all the momenta to get the Dirac delta distribution. It is, however, not relativistically invariant and not physically sensible. Why would you want to do this?